# Starting a video by hovering over a div

Tags: html, jquery, video, mouseover

I used this solution to start videos (each separately) when I hover them:

```
//play video on hover
$(document).on('mouseover', 'video', function() { 
$(this).get(0).play(); 
}); 

//pause video on mouse leave
$(document).on('mouseleave', 'video', function() { 
$(this).get(0).pause(); 
});
```

It works really nice. But actually I want to start a video when I hover its titles (so another div, start each video separately when hovering its own titles). Does anyone has a solution for that?

I have my Titles in a div called »video-titles« and my videos embedded like this:

```
<HTML Embed>
 <div id="w-embed">
 <video class="video" position= "absolute" top= "0px" margin= "0 auto" height= "auto" width= "100%" preload="auto" muted loop>
 <source src="myvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />
 </video>   
 </div>
```

Here is my site:https://monkeyberlin-preview-3a28-d94aa03c105a2.webflow.io/
Cheers and thanks for the help!

Comment: `Does anyone has a solution for that?` -> yes , if you can show the HTML part. Otherwise no

Comment: add it in your question as well as where is `title` in your given HTML code?

Comment: oh sorry, see update, thx for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is an example to play a video when you hover its title.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".video_inside h3").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('video')[0].play();
  }, function() {
    var el = $(this).parent().children("video")[0];
    el.pause();
    el.currentTime = 0;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_inside">
  <video preload="auto" muted="muted" loop>
        <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
  <h3>Video Title</h3>
</div>
```

Note: make sure to paste the JS code below the jQuery file.

Comment: You can find the working code at codepen. https://codepen.io/hassanmehmood/pen/YzpMeLo

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery.js to the snippet. I added it for you to save people having to go off-site to see the code working

Comment: I already mentioned in a note to make sure you have added the jQuery file :) Thank anyway :)

Comment: This is the only one working so far but just as long as the titles are in the same div with the video. 
But my titles are in a div with z-index 1 above the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#title').hover(function() {
    $('#video').get(0).play(); 
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: Hi thx, my titles are in a separate div and it seems not to work then...